# Recursive QuerySet with django

Tags: django, django-queryset, recursive-query

I have this model referencing itself to allow building a tree:

```
class PartCategory(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('PartCategory', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, default=None, blank=True)
    name = models.TextField()
```

I now have an SQL query to get one element and all of its child in one select (in this example the element with id=64):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  under_partcategory(id,name, parent_id,level) AS (
    select api_partcategory.id,api_partcategory.name,api_partcategory.parent_id,0 from api_partcategory where api_partcategory.id=64
    UNION ALL
    SELECT api_partcategory.id,api_partcategory.name,api_partcategory.parent_id, under_partcategory.level+1
    FROM api_partcategory JOIN under_partcategory ON api_partcategory.parent_id=under_partcategory.id
    ORDER BY 2
  )
SELECT * FROM under_partcategory;
```

I am searching a way to express this query inside a QuerySet to allow adding filtering options and fields construction from my model but I don't quite know if it's kind of possible.

Can I construct a composite QuerySet made from some kind of raw query built from my model, and at the same time allowing to use the `filter` and `order_by` capabilities?

**Edit:**

To be more specific I would like to have a QuerySet I can use this whay:

```
PartCategory.recursive.filter(64)
```

Internally it would build the request by replacing all embraced parts with elements from PartCategory model:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  under_{model name}({model fields},level) AS (
    select {model fields},0 from {model name} {where {model name}.id=64 #extracted from filter}
    UNION ALL
    SELECT {model fields}, under_{model_name}.level+1
    FROM {model name} JOIN under_{model_name} ON {model_name}.parent_id=under_{model_name}.id
    ORDER BY 2
  )
SELECT * FROM under_{model_name};
```

I'm playing with a custom managers to try to build this but for now I don't know how to build `{model fields}` from my model and how to return an object eligible for `filter`.

**Edit 2:**

As stated by colwin I made it with `django-mptt` but not exactly as I was thinking in first place.

My model with `django-mptt` becomes:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class PartCategory(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
    name = models.TextField()
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
```

And to extract my item 64 with all its childrens I now do:

```
categories = PartCategory.objects.get(id=64).get_descendants(include_self=True)
```

This is quite straightforward !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't this work for you?

```
parts = PartCategory.objects.raw('''
    WITH RECURSIVE
    under_partcategory(id,name, parent_id,level) AS (
    select   api_partcategory.id,api_partcategory.name,api_partcategory.parent_id,0 from api_partcategory where api_partcategory.id=64
    UNION ALL
    SELECT api_partcategory.id,api_partcategory.name,api_partcategory.parent_id, under_partcategory.level+1
    FROM api_partcategory JOIN under_partcategory ON api_partcategory.parent_id=under_partcategory.id
    ORDER BY 2
  )
SELECT * FROM under_partcategory;
''')
```

You can also look at https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

Comment: That was my first try, I want to go further (I edited my question to be more specific)

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at django-mptt? Its built to handle trees like your case. I've not used it much or recently but it looks like it fits what you need done.

Comment: Definitively yes, entirely fits my needs, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Or check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw

```
id = 64

parts = PartCategory.objects.raw('''
    WITH RECURSIVE
    under_partcategory(id,name, parent_id,level) AS (
    select   api_partcategory.id,api_partcategory.name,api_partcategory.parent_id,0 from api_partcategory where api_partcategory.id=%s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT api_partcategory.id,api_partcategory.name,api_partcategory.parent_id, under_partcategory.level+1
    FROM api_partcategory JOIN under_partcategory ON api_partcategory.parent_id=under_partcategory.id
    ORDER BY 2
  )
SELECT * FROM under_partcategory;
''', [id])
```

Note the `%s` substitution at the raw query.