# Django get all child and subchilds of a parent

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

i have a model that have self-referenced to itself , i want to get all child and child of child and so on in one query.
is there any queryset to get all child related to a parent ?

Comment: please, add comment to the question

Comment: possibly answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903948/recursive-queryset-with-django

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar in a project before except I was using SQLAlachemy. You could add a property or a classmethod on the model which does something like my method below:

Except you would alter the list comprehension to use the Django relationship query(M2M, Foreign key).

Since you already have the object when using the property below you can do something like this inside the list comprehension for a M2M relationship query:

`[c.serialize for c in self.related_column.all()]`

```
    @property
    def serialize(self):
        """ Returns a json serializable dict.

        Notes:
            What's cool about this is that the children's key recursively keeps
            calling itself on all of the children of each new node. Causing the
            output to look like which is pretty powerful.

            - Root
                - level_1  
                    - level_2
                        - level_3
                - level_1  
                    - level_2
                        - level_3
                - level_1  
                    - level_2
                        - level_3

        Returns:
            dict: Key value pairs of essential Node data.
        """
        base = {
            'id':                self.id,
            'name':              self.name,
            'min_num':           self.min_num,
            'max_num':           self.max_num,
            'parent_id':         self.parent_id,
            'can_have_children': self.can_have_children

        }
        if self.can_have_children:
            return {**base, 'children': [c.serialize for c in self.sub_nodes]}
        else:
            return base
```